# How to create List<T> instance in C# when using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, iteration

I have a class with some Generic Properties in it and also some other types of property:

```cs
 private ObservableCollection<SelectFood> _breakfasts = new ObservableCollection<SelectFood>();

 public ObservableCollection<SelectFood> Breakfasts
 {
     get { return _breakfasts; }
     set { SetProperty(ref _breakfasts, value); }
 }

 private ObservableCollection<SelectFood> _lunches = new ObservableCollection<SelectFood>();
 public ObservableCollection<SelectFood> Lunches
 {
     get { return _lunches; }
     set
     { SetProperty(ref _lunches, value); }
 }

 private TblDailyFoodList _foodinfo = new TblDailyFoodList();
 public TblDailyFoodList Foodinfo
 {
     get { return _foodinfo; }
     set { SetProperty(ref _foodinfo, value); }
 }
```

`SelectFood` is a `userControl` with some Field, property and ...

Now, In a Method I want to iterate over properties of this class and if property is of type  `ObservableCollection<SelectFood>` , Depend on it's name, do some work:

```cs
private void SelectedFoods()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DailyFoodListViewModel).GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<SelectFood>))
        {
            foreach (var item in property)
            {
                if (item.IsChkbxChecked == true)
                {
                    Foodinfo.Foods += item.MyTblFoodInfo.FoodType + string.Format(item.MyTblFoodInfo.Id.ToString("000"));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem:
in `foreach (var item in property)`  loop, I can not use `property` directly.
How can I use `property` in foreach loop?

Comment: Sounds like you want `foreach (var item in (ObservableCollection<SelectFood>)property.GetValue(model)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the collection itself, you need to use the GetValue() method of the PropertyInfo object

```
private void SelectedFoods()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DailyFoodListViewModel).GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<SelectFood>))
        {
            IEnumerable<SelectFood> collection = (IEnumerable<SelectFood>)property.GetValue(this);

            foreach (SelectFood item in collection)
            {
                if (item.IsChkbxChecked == true)
                {
                    Foodinfo.Foods += item.MyTblFoodInfo.FoodType + string.Format(item.MyTblFoodInfo.Id.ToString("000"));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is a statically typed language.  Using reflection to build your list loses a lot of the benefits of that.

Instead, since almost certainly know what `ObservableCollections` are present, you should probably be doing something like:

```
var list = new List<SelectFood>();

list.Concat(Breakfasts);
list.Concat(Lunches);
//... for each meal

return result;
```

If you absolutely must use reflection, you need to call `property.GetValue`,  something like this:

```
private void SelectedFoods()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DailyFoodListViewModel).GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<SelectFood>))
        {
            foreach (var item in (ObservableCollection<SelectFood>)property.GetValue(this))
            {
                if (item.IsChkbxChecked == true)
                {
                    Foodinfo.Foods += item.MyTblFoodInfo.FoodType + string.Format(item.MyTblFoodInfo.Id.ToString("000"));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```